# Finitely generated module with a submodule that is not finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

> Can someone give an example of a ring $R$, a left $R$-module $M$ and a submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $M$ is finitely generated, but $N$ is not finitely generated?

I tried a couple of examples of modules I know and got nothing...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Consider the simplest possible nontrivial (left) $R$-module: $R$ itself. It's certainly finitely generated, by $\{ 1 \}$. The submodules are exactly the (left) ideals of $R$. So you want a ring which has (left) ideals which are not finitely generated. For example, you could use a non-Noetherian commutative ring, such as $\mathbb{Z}[X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots ]$.

Comment: Even more is true: A ring $R$ is noetherian if and only if submodules of f.g. modules over $R$ are f.g.

Comment: But wouldn't the ideal be finitely generates as well? I am sorry I know this is a basic question but I am stuck at this point. So for the given example, $R=\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2, \cdots]$, one of the ideals could be the polynomials of $I=\mathbb{Z}[X_1]$. This can also be generated by $\{1\}$. I know that for all the polynomials in this ideal, we need countably many different powers of $X_1$. Is that why it is not finitely generated?

Comment: @PythonSage Check out my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4607750/507382). I have written out almost every detail and it is as clear as crystal.