# Presentations of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-presentation

I've been looking into finding the presentation of subgroups $H$ of $G$ from a known presentation of the group $G$.
I know that usually, removing generators but keeping the set of relations the same can give presentations of subgroups. However, I've heard that there are instances where a subgroup might actually require more generators than the group itself. Does anyone know of any concrete examples of this that they can explain/know of where I can find an explanation?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/subgroups-of-finitely-generated-groups-are-not-necessarily-finitely-generated) might interest you.

Comment: This looks like an interesting discussion! Thanks for the link :)

Comment: It is not true that "removing generators but keeping the set of relations the same" usually gives a presentation of a subgroup. In fact usually you will still have relations that involve the removed generators, and so what remains will not be a presentation at all.

Comment: Apologies that"s just what I'd heard; obviously the remaining relations would need to be altered to account for removed generators...

Answer (score 3):

This can happen even for finite groups: every finite group is a subgroup of a 2-generator group, namely a symmetric group.  The simplest example of finite groups which requires more than two generators is $C_2 \oplus C_2 \oplus C_2$, where $C_2$ is cyclic of order 2.  For infinite groups, it is a theorem Higman, Neumann and Neumann that every countable group is a subgroup of a group generated by two elements.

To find presentations of subgroups of a finitely presented group in practice, you may want to read about the [Todd-Coxeter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd%E2%80%93Coxeter_algorithm).