# A finitely generated group that contains a subgroup which is not finitely generated.

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Question: Give a finitely generated group that contains a subgroup which is not finitely generated.

What I know: I learned that the free group with two generators $F_{2}$ (with 2 by 2 matrix generators)  is finitely generated. But I do not know what the subgroup of it which is not finitely generated. Can some one help me find such a subgroup? I would appreciate!

Comment: It's not hard to show that ***any*** countable group can be embedded in a finitely generated group. So you can get an example like you want by taking any non-finitely-generated countable group (for example the additive group of the rational numbers) and embedding it in a finitely generated group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subgroups of finitely generated groups are not necessarily finitely generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/subgroups-of-finitely-generated-groups-are-not-necessarily-finitely-generated)

Answer (score 5):

The free group on countable many generators, $F_{\infty}$, is isomorphic to a subgroup of $F_2$. Write $F_2 = \langle x,y\rangle$ and take $F_{\infty}$ to be the subgroup generated freely by $yxy^{-1}, y^2xy^{-2}, y^3xy^{-3} \ldots$.

There is a nice way to see this from the theory of covering spaces. Take $F_2$ to be the fundamental group of the wedge of two circles labelled $x$ and $y$. Then consider the covering space that consists of basepoints indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$, with each basepoint $n$ having two edges labelled $x$ and $y$ going to the point $n+1$.