# Does there exist a geometric action of a non-finitely generated group on a non-proper geodesic metric space?

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces

I am studying Svarc-Milnor lemma :

*If a group $G$ acts geometrically on a proper geodesic metric space $(X,d)$, then $G$ is finitely generated and any of its Cayley graphs (with some finite generating subset) is quasi-isometric to $(X,d)$.*

I would like to check with examples the necessity of each hypothesis in the lemma. In particular, I'm having trouble finding a geometric action of a non-finitely generated group on a non-proper geodesic metric space.

I was thinking about the space $l_2$ (of sequences) which is not proper, but I don't find any geometric action with it (for example with reflexions, it is not cocompact).

**Note** : geometrically means that the action is by isometry, properly discontinuous and cocompact (the set of orbits is compact). The properly discontinuity means here that for every compact $K \subset X$, there exists only a finite number of $g  \in G$  such that $ g \cdot K$ intersects $K$.

Thank you.

Comment: What examples have you checked?  What research have you done into your question?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2945138/472818

Comment: You should spell out the definition of a geometric action, otherwise people will misunderstand your question.

Comment: And your definition of proper discontinuity needs a correction. What book are you reading?

Comment: The answer to the question is negative, but a proof is a bit long. I will write a sketch once the question is reopened. Moreover, one can even  prove that a geodesic metric space $X$ is proper, provided it admits a geometric group action.

Comment: @mr_e_man: The linked example is irrelevant since the action there is not cocompact.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Thank you! Is there some paper that explains this?

Comment: I saw something like this recently, I will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can drop the properness (of $X$) assumption in the M-S lemma. You can find a proof (a bit sketchy but correct) in

*Roe, John*, Lectures on coarse geometry, University Lecture Series 31. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-3332-4/pbk). vii, 175 p. (2003). [ZBL1042.53027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1042.53027).

Specifically, see pages 8-10.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.