# Why is the free group on two generators not a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups, solvable-groups, wreath-product

Let $G$ be generated by the elements $g$ and $\{e_i\}$ for $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, having the relation $ge_ig^{-1}=e_{i+1}$.

It seems to me like there is a subgroup $\langle e_i,e_{i+1}\rangle$ for example, that is the free group on two generators. But I also know that this group is solvable (although I don't know how to prove it) and that the free group on two generators is *not* solvable. Thus cannot be a subgroup. Is there a direct argument to see that the group generated by two of the $e_i$'s is not the free group on two generators?

Edit: It turns out this group is only solvable when $e_i e_j = e_j  e_i$

Comment: How certain are you that this group is solvable? I don't see it. In fact, this looks to me like an HNN extension of a free group generated by the $e_i$'s.

Comment: Well, I suppose it might not be... 
My professor asked us to prove that it is solvable on a Homework. It is supposed to be an example of a group that *is* solvable but is *not* polycyclic.

Comment: Perhaps you have left off some relations? Are $e_i,e_j$ required to commute?

Comment: Well perhaps my professor did. I will check and update my question.

Comment: During class he mentioned that this was a "wreath product" and an answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/subgroups-of-finitely-generated-groups-are-not-necessarily-finitely-generated

gives a description that seems to be the same as the description of the group in my homework.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/308229/30382

Comment: If it is a wreath product, then the $e_i$ commute; what you have is the restricted wreath product of the infinite cyclic group by itself, $\mathbb{Z}\wr_r\mathbb{Z}$. But in the wreath product $A\wr_r B$, you take a direct sum (restricted direct product) of $|B|$ copies of $A$, and then $B$ acts on this sum by acting on the indices. So if your group is supposed to be a wreath product, then you are missing the relations $e_ie_j=e_je_i$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: @pictorexcrucia: The difference between the description given by Andreas in the question you link to and yours is that he explicitly says the base group is abelian (“coproduct in the category of abelian groups”) whereas your description does not say that $\langle e_i\mid i\in\mathbb{Z}\rangle$ is abelian.